# Issue with passing parameters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="SendClass(this);">Toggle class</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function SendClass(sender)
{       console.log(sender); 

}
</script>
```

I can send `this` to function SendClass(sender) through `onclick="SendClass(this)`, and `event` to function SendClass(sender) through `onclick="SendClass(event)`, so my questions are:

1.why we can pass parameters `this` and `event` to `function SendClass(sender)`?

2.what parameters else I can pass to `function SendClass(sender)` to be used?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. Anything you want. Just define the function to accept two or more arguments (`SendClass(arg1, arg2, ...)`) and pass two ore more arguments. Learn more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html.

Comment: I don't see any jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.why we can pass parameters this and event to function SendClass(sender)?

The code within the `onxyz` attribute is run in a context which has `this` (the element) and `event` the event in it. So you can use both of those in that code, including passing them into a function you call.

> 2.what parameters else I can pass to function SendClass(sender) to be used?

Those are pretty much the only two useful ones defined by the context. You can, of course, pass anything *else* you like, but those are the two most useful of the ones defined by the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this and event, because they are available at the context. You can pass your variables if you like. For example:

```
SendClass(1, "test", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `this` keyword is used to pass the object of that element and here is used to get the object of anchor tag in your code.
2. You can pass any parameter that you want.
3. You can pass the `this.href` and for input type this.value etc.
4. And to call that function you need to same number of parameters that you pass at the time of call the function.
   Such as if you are passing the 2 parameters then you need to declare 2 parameters in the function.